# Moved PHP from Linux & Apache to Windows & IIS - Problems

Tags: php, windows, iis

I am seeing the following error when attempting to serve my PHP files in IIS on Windows, everything was fine on my linux server.

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter -
headers already sent (output started at 
C:\Inetpub\vhosts\test\httpdocs\signup.php:1) in 
C:\Inetpub\vhosts\test\httpdocs\signup.php on line 1
```

The first line is:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

Here is what I have tried:

Save file as UTF8 in Gedit
Save in geany - Properties shows 'UTF-8 (without BOM)'
Tested the file on http://people.w3.org/rishida/utils/bomtester/index.php and the result is:

```
No BOM
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check if you send data before call the php session start function. It can be a newline, a space ... This error is documented in the php doc for the function `session_start()`